# server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2

In my website everything is  worked perfectly but after all html tags end  this error will be appear:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>200 OK</title>
</head><body>
<h1>OK</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

htaccess file is:

```
Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

how to hide or resolve this issue.

Comment: Please could you upload image here..?